# How to migrate UWP application to Desktop application in .Net

Tags: uwp, desktop

I have two application that is created in VS2019

1. UWP  App
2. Desktop Form Application

Now i am run both application separately so now i want to marge both application in Desktop application

When i run Desktop Form Application UWP Application should be Run so how can i achieve this

Comment: "UWP WPF App" makes no sense. It's either the one or the other.

Comment: it's UWP application

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by installing the Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts
package and migrate it within the WinForms / WPF application. This means that you can have a WinForms or WPF application that can use UWP libraries. You will not be able to use the UI elements of UWP, but you will be able to use its C# libraries within your WinForms or WPF application.

This can be done by using the above mentioned SDK.

Here is the link for the SDK project's page: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Windows.SDK.Contracts

Here is a link about how to migrate the package-configuration to the package-reference (the References section of the C# solution):
https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/26/calling-windows-10-apis-from-your-wpf-application/